# IIS access website via https and not http

Tags: angular, iis, https, iisnode

I have my website running at http://localhost/index.html#/ but I want this to run in https://localhost/index.html#/. I have certificate installed at IIS level(under server certificate). When I go to SSL cerificate for under default web site [image: SSL certificate disabled]

How do access website in https rather from http?

Please note: I have added certificate at the IIS level as shown in picture below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a site binding for https

1. Click on "Default Web Site"
2. On the "Actions" pane on the right side, select "Bindings"

   - You will likely only see a row for `http` and port `80` but no row for `https`
3. Click "Add" and select `https` for "Type." The "Port" field should default to `443`
4. Click "OK" and run `iisreset`